# Is there a way to rewrite the SQL query efficiently?

Tags: sql, teradata

I know, this is probably a very basic and simple SQL question, but I'm looking for a way to improve the SQL statement below.

```
SELECT 
    ANY_COLUMN
FROM 
    MY_TABLE
WHERE 
    ATTR1='ABC'
AND 
    ATR2 = 'DEF'
AND 
    CAST(STRTOK((
        SELECT 
            ANY_COLUMN 
        FROM 
            MY_TABLE
        WHERE 
            ATTR1='ABC'
        AND 
            ATR2 ='DEF'
        ), '.', 4) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') 
    > 
    CAST(STRTOK('sometext.sometext.20100101.txt', '.', 4) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD');
```

The query gives me the result, I'm looking for, but I doubt, that it is very performant.
As you can see, I'm filterting twice for the same attributes on the same table.

Is there a way to improve the performance of this query? 
Maybe with a self join?

Comment: Your subquery does not make sense, because it should return only 1 row (and the same one) to be cast to date.

Comment: Yes. My subquery returns 1 row. Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Why do you apply the 2nd STRTOK on a literal instead of `> DATE '2010-01-01'`?

Comment: @dnoeth Because I only get this literal. It is a filename. For my question, this doesn't matter. It could also be `DATE '2001-01-01`'`

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: You could split the conditions and apply the first two in a Derived Table and the 3rd in the outer Select. If this still fails I would consider it as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that subquery is not necessary

```
SELECT 
    ANY_COLUMN
FROM 
    MY_TABLE
WHERE 
    ATTR1='ABC'
AND 
    ATR2 = 'DEF'
AND 
    TO_NUMBER(STRTOK(ANY_COLUMN, '.', 4)) > 
    TO_NUMBER(STRTOK('sometext.sometext.20100101.txt', '.', 4));
```

Moreover, to process the query efficiently index on `(attr1, atr2)` is needed:

```
create index ix_mytable_attr1_atr2(attr1, atr2) on MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Since the structure of the varchar stored in ANY_COLUMN changes, depending on ATTR1 and ATR2, the date cast does not always work. If I change my query the way you suggested, I get an error "Invalid date".

Comment: Use `TO_NUMBER(STRTOK(ANY_COLUMN, '.', 4))` to avoid the casting error